# Interllij IDEA PERL5 sdk is not configured

Tags: perl, intellij-idea

I have perl plugin installed in IDEA, and I have MinGW64 installed in Windows 7. In MinGW64 I can see `perl -V`:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 22 subversion 1) configuration
...

  @INC:
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/core_perl
    .
```

But in Intellij IDEA `Perl5 interpreter: Diable Perl5 support` is the only option. I thought it should be a 2nd option for the plugin. Now I can only add it manually, but I am freshman in perl, I don't know which one is perl interpreter. I have expanded many folders(core, vendor, lib...), and still cannot find the one that IDEA thinks it is an interpreter.

Comment: Have you check these steps https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Getting-started ?

Answer (score 4):

In front of the Perl Interpreter dropdown menu, you can see an options menu(Three dots vertically) from that you can add the Perl interpreter from your local machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can install perl latest version.
2. Click on configure perl SDK on IntelliJ.
3. Click on 3 dot beside perl interpreter.
4. You will have 3 option out of them select add perlbrew.
5. Select the latest perl installation directory bin -> perlbrew.
6. Local perlbrew should be setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when you update IntelliJ Idea, and the plugin. The run configuration cannot be run, with the following error:
*Run Configuration Error: Unable to detect perl interpreter for a project your_project_name*.

While the question is for Windows, I will give an answer for Linux.

Go to **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Perl5**.
There, for the *Project* line, on the *Perl5* tab, you will see a *Perl5 Interpreter:* field set to *Disable Perl5 support*.
Click a gear icon next to it, and select *Add System Perl*. Select path */usr/bin/perl*. Press OK.

[image]